# Angular Ionic reacitve form wont call ngSubmit function, page refreshes instead

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to create a Reactive form in an Angular (v12) and Ionic (v6) project.
When I submit the form, rather than call the submit function specified in the form tags ngSubmit property, the page just appears to refresh.  The application is based on ionic tabs in case that could be causing an issue?  I have imported the ReactiveFormsModule into the the page module rather than the app module, as the various tutorials I have read advise you need to do this when using with Ionic.

profile.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ProfilePage } from './profile.page';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    
@NgModule({
   imports: [
     CommonModule,    
     IonicModule,
     FormsModule,
     ReactiveFormsModule,
   ],
   declarations: [ProfilePage]
})    

export class ProfilePageModule {}
```

profile.page.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Profile } from '../shared/models/profile';
import { ProfileService } from './profile.service';
    
@Component({
   selector: 'app-profile',
   templateUrl: './profile.page.html',
   styleUrls: ['./profile.page.scss'],
})

export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {    
  profileForm : FormGroup   
  constructor(private _profileService: ProfileService) {}
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.profileForm = new FormGroup({
        firstName: new FormControl(),
        middleName: new FormControl(),
        lastName: new FormControl(),
        dob: new FormControl(),
        companyId: new FormControl()
      });
    }
 
    save() {
      console.log('test');
    }
}
```

profile.page.html

```html
<ion-content>
   <form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="save()" novalidate>
   <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
         <ion-label>First Name</ion-label>
         <ion-input 
            id="firstName"
            type="text"
            required
            formControlName="firstName">
         </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
         <ion-label>Middle Name</ion-label>
         <ion-input
            id="middleName"
            type="text"
            formControlName="middleName">
         </ion-input>
         >
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
         <ion-label>Last Name</ion-label>
         <ion-input
            id="lastName"
            type="text"
            formControlName="lastName">
         </ion-input>
         >
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
         <ion-label>DOB</ion-label>
         <ion-input 
            id="dob"
            type="date"
            formControlName="dob">
         </ion-input>
         >
      </ion-item>
      <ion-button form="profileForm"
         expand="block"
         type="submit"
         [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">
         Save
      </ion-button>
   </ion-list>
   </form>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce it with Button Properties:
This worked and stopped the whole page from reloading:
as `<button type="button"`
or

1. I changed the button type from "submit" to "button"
2. I introduced a **(click)= submitValues()** inside the button props like this :
   submit

i.e. `<button type="submit" (click)= submitValues()>Submit Form</button>`

This stopped the page from reloading, I hope this helps.

Comment: Did You get it?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have tried as you suggested which stops the page from reloading.  However, it doesn't  seem to pass any of the form data back, I just get null values returned using either this.profileForm.get('firstName') or this.profileForm.value.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by importing `profile.module.ts` into the `AppModule`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what I did was mistakenly put the `<ion-button>` after closing the `</form>` which prevent it from triggering the event. Solved it by puting the  `<ion-button>` and than closing the `<form>` tag.